# Flutter Lifecycle: How to correctly use dispose()?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and currently have a very basic app where I've managed to implement the Application Life cycle Management. If the app has been closed it returns `AppLifecycleState.inactive` then `AppLifecycleState.paused` then when I open it up again it returns `AppLifecycleState.resume`, Which all works fine. My issue is I want the life cycle to only work on one of my pages, when I navigate to a second page I want the life cycle to stop.

How can I use the `dispose()` on my second page to stop the life cycle?

I was thinking about importing my first file into my second file then calling the `dispose()`, but would that work?

I know the `dispose()` is used to end the life cycle which I can trigger if its on the file but I would like to trigger it within another file.

Is what im asking evening possible or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Tutorial Lifecycle'),
      ),
      body: Center(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making new separated service for lifecycle like this.

```
class MyLibrary with WidgetsBindingObserver {
      AppLifecycleState? _state;
    
      AppLifecycleState? get state => _state;
    
      MyLibrary() {
        WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
      }
    
      /// make sure the clients of this library invoke the dispose method
      /// so that the observer can be unregistered
      void dispose() {
        WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
      }
    
      @override
      void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
        this._state = state;
      }
    
      void someFunctionality() {
        // your library feature
      }
 }
```

Now you can dispose life cycle at any page by using

```
MyLibrary().dispose();
```

Comment: This does not work... the dispose function does not triggers.